# Windows 10 - Mapped Drive Issue - Keep losing connection

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, mapped-drive

I have a mapped drive on my home network that is getting some strange behavior this last week. I did take the Windows 10 2004 update on 6/17 and wonder if it is related.

I have a drive on my home network that I have mapped.  Periodically when I boot up my PC the mapped drive does not work.  What makes this really strange is that sometimes if I try to access it directly through the start run menu, it works.  What makes it more strange is that sometimes I can access it through the UNC path ("\mybookworld") but not the IP address ("\192.168.1.100") and other times it is the other way around.  It used to always work either way.  I end up not being able to use the mapped drive when I have the option selected that is not working.

This is an older Western Digital World Book drive that uses SMB1 for file sharing.

Anyone have any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this type of intermittent issue in the past by adding an entry in the hosts file like this

192.168.1.100 mybookworld

You should also ensure that mybookworld is allocated a static or reserved IP address (terms used vary per router)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I did not think about the hosts file.  I did have it with a static IP.  I ended up needed to reset my router to factory defaults for another issue and so far this one has not come back after the reset.  Looks like that was my answer.  Thanks for jumping in.